# Modeling inheritance in relationnal databases

Tags: database, inheritance, jooq

I'm currently trying to figure out how to model inheritance in relationnal databases (i mean modeling inheritance like object oriented programming style).
I'll be using **Jooq** to do so and I'm in front of severals problems.
Imagine that i have 3 objects : Animal, Dog, Cat.
Cat and Dog inherits from Animal.

I saw that there's 3 mainstream ways to do so :

- MTI (Multitables inheritance, each objet have it's own table and a parent table exist to modelize the parent, So there will be three tables, animal_table, dog_table and cat_table)
- Single Table (all Cat, Dog and Animal will be stored in the same table all_animals)

In Cat and Dog, i have severals informations specifics to Cat and Dog. Now, imagine that i need to get from an Animal Id the corresponding concrete object, so either a Cat or a Dog.
One way would be to :
1 - Get the Animal from animal table
2 - Determine the type of the animal (let's assume it's a Dog)
3 - Getting the dog directly from the table Dog

What annoys me is that i'll have to do severals request to do so. Do you know how i can achieve this without using several requests (one simple would be the best) ?)
Because now, image that i have N distincts animals (Parrot, Mouse, Dog, Cat, ...) i will have to first get the type of this animal, and then request the proper table, Parrot, Mouse, Dog, Cat and so on. I want to avoid this.

Comment: There are at least 5 solutions to model inheritance in relational databases. Should your model accept abstract rows (e.g. just an animal) or all insertions must be concrete?

Comment: What's a real world use case rather than animals?

Comment: Animal is abstract, all insertions must be concrete

Comment: This is very hypothetical. It's not even necessarily a good idea to use inheritance for this strawman example, even harder to say what the best approach would have been for your real world use case. With the very limited knowledge about what you're trying to do, I'd say, just normalise your data model as you always would, and don't get lured into the traps of data inheritance, which are hardly ever worth it. If, however, I knew what your real world use-case was, maybe, there could have been an exception to my general opinion, and a different model might have been better. Hard to say.

Comment: Well, actually my real use case is the following : I have a system of folders. Each folder can contains objects. Each object contains sheets_revisions. And finally my sheet_revision could be of multiple types : sheet about a person, sheet about a house, sheet about a bike an so on. My inheritance is there to modelize that each house sheet, bike sheet and so on inherits from sheet_revision.